How can I verify compatibility of a T8 replacement tube?
I've got an issue with a fluorescent fitting. There are 2 bulbs. However, one darkened at the end so has burnt out. I am trying to source a replacement but it seems like the manufacturer of this bulb no longer sells them. Does the diameter of the bulb matter and what else should I look for in sourcing a replacement?
Also, what exactly do the numbers mean (aside from the 58W which I presume is watts)?
It is also a 2pin on each end.
This is the bulb

Some searching says T8 is a tube that is 8x1/8(1 inch) diameter, so that a main point plus the length.  Watts are more for the amount of light given off, so probably changeable if too bright/dim to you.

Personally, I'd remove the ballast and replace the fluorescent tubes with LED's. I find LED lamps last far longer than fluorescents and provide more light for the same power.

Does it have a small st111 starter?
If yes, probably  Sylvania 24729
If no, probably Philips TL-D 58W/33-640 1SL/25
